# Handling error in a source code of other schema

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, stored-functions

I have a source code of a function in Oracle PL/SQL from other schema and I can not change it. How  can I handle it if it throws error?

Comment: It depends on what error you want to handle? Could you elaborate more with the details of exception and what you would like to handle?

Comment: Yaa VN'sCorner , Actually what is the technical solution in plsql to handle errors from a function If I can not change any thing of it I mean not even a colon .And code is coming to from other schema and I have to resolve it on my own without telling him who created it. Solid I use Plugin please suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using that function and depend on the result it returns **+** worry whether it'll fail (well, who says it will? Maybe it is failproof), then good news for you: as that function isn't alone in space, you can create a **wrapper** function in your own schema. Your function would call the "original" and handle possible exceptions.

Here's a simple example, just to illustrate what I mean.

Connected as `mike`, I'll create function that returns an error (and grant it to `scott`):

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> create or replace function f_fail return number as
  2  begin
  3    return 1/0;
  4  end;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_fail from dual;
select f_fail from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "MIKE.F_FAIL", line 3


SQL> grant execute on f_fail to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as `scott` and call that function; of course, it'll fail:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> select mike.f_fail from dual;
select mike.f_fail from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "MIKE.F_FAIL", line 3
```

OK, let's create the *wrapper* function and see how it behaves (I'll use `when others` which is probably the worst exception handler; I'd suggest you to take smarter approach and handle exceptions as they happen).

```
SQL> create or replace function f_wrapper return number as
  2  begin
  3    return mike.f_fail;
  4  exception
  5    when others then
  6      return 0;
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_wrapper from dual;

 F_WRAPPER
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Aha! No more *dividing by zero* error!

---

See if it helps.

Comment: I guess there is no foolproof solution, unless the exception to be handled is user defined exception.